# Force exception on missing non-null properties

Tags: c#, validation, properties, initialization, c#-record-type

I have a simple record like this:

```cs
public record Filter
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
}
```

The property is explicitly not non-null. I want the framework to throw an exception when the type `Filter` is initialized without the ID. How do I do that?

Right now it just puts "0" as a default value and I have no idea of the broken initialization.

Comment: if you want validation: write a class or struct with a constructor, and perform your validation in there

Comment: Usually this means you want to have a parametrized constructor with int id as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a constructor:

```
public record Filter(int Id);
```

Now, you will get compiler errors if it is not explicitely given an Id. That's preferable to runtime exceptions anyway.

Comment: This does not work with frameworks like AutoMapper or MVC, though.

Comment: AutoMapper seems to work just fine. WebAPI too. I'm not using MVC though, you might be right about that.

Comment: I added the solution for MVC below, just as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a way that works with `[ApiController]`, so the above doesn't work for me (but I didn't specify that, because I didn't know it would be different). So if the validation is for REST, the accepted answer won't work, the right way is:

```
public record Filter
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; init; }
}
```

(Note that the int must be nullable, else the framework will default it to 0 and the required validation will never be done.)

With that setup, the endpoint will automatically return HTTP code 400 if the required field is missing.